# Is there a way to purify polluted ground?

Tags: simcity-2013

When ground is polluted by various ways (garbage piles, sewer exits etc) can it be purified somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can plant trees. In the Nature(§§) tab, click the right arrow.
Trees will eventually die and will have to be replanted. It takes time but it will clean pollution up.

Comment: Aha, was looking for the trees